# AddThis Plugin didn't share images to different social handle?

Tags: facebook, twitter, drupal-7, social-networking, addthis

I have used the AddThis Plugin in one of my Drupal sites to share the blogs, guides etc. on the Social Sites, but the content that is shared doesn't appear with images on the social sites.

Answer (score 1):

To share your link (not localhost link) on Facebook with the image, you can detect your link in [Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) of Facebook to know what your Open Graph properties are missed. Like this [Object Debbuger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP9E8.png).

Then, you need to provide the Open Graph properties that your site doesn't have.

If you don't have experience in this, you can use the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) contributed module. This module lets you config the Open Graph properties for your site (need to enable metatag_open_graph children module). The module still has a configuration for Facebook, Twitter, Google + (Google stopped this social), so try testing and you can choose the best way for your site.